# How to sign out of QField app on Windows

Tags: qfield, windows, qfield-cloud, user-account

I am using QField but I signed in with a different account. I now can't seem to sign out, so I can sign back in with the correct QFieldCloud account. There does not seem to be a sign out button.

How can I do this?
I have uninstalled it and reinstalled and I still get the same.